# Сьезжает DIV с position:absolute при масштабировании

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Я относительно недавно начал изучать css и html и столкнулся с одной проблемой: при уменьшении масштаба страницы у меня сьезжает блок c текстом **GO AHEAD** с абсолютным позиционированием. Свойству left и bottom прописал значение в процентах, но с уменьшением масштаба он все равно сьезжает по-тихоньку вправо.  Подскажите пожалуйста решение данной проблемы, чтобы блок при изменения масштаба оставался в такой же позиции, в которой был вначале.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>ScreenDesign</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&family=Rokkitt&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="header-intro">
                        <div class="logo"> Logo
                        </div>

                        <nav class="nav">
                            <a class="nav-links" href="#">Start</a>
                            <a class="nav-links" href="#">About me</a>
                            <a class="nav-links" href="#">Work</a>
                            <a class="nav-links" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                <div class="section2">
                    
                    <div class="header-title">
                        <div class="header-title-item">
                            <h1 class="title-text">May I introduce myself?</h1>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="header-subtitle-item">
                            <h2 class="subtitle-text">Frontend Design | UI/UX Design
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <a class="header-link" href="#">
                        <div class="header-button">
                            <div class="header-button-text">Go ahead
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    
  
</body>
</html>

    html {
    font-size: 15px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
    
    font-size: 1rem;
    
    line-height: 1;
    
    background-color: white;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1020px;
    
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 58px;
    
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}





.header {

    
    width: 100%;
    
    height: 500px;
    
    background: url(img/header.jpg) center no-repeat;
    
    background-size: cover;
}

.section2 {
    position: relative;
}


.header-intro {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}



.logo {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.nav-links {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    
    margin: 0 15px;
    
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.nav-links:hover {
    color: #1abc9c;
}



.header-title {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    margin-top: 150px;
    
    color: white;
}



.title-text {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 60px;
    
    padding: 0 35px 10px 35px;
    
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.subtitle-text {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    
    margin-top: 15px;
}





.header-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -180%;
    left: 38%;
    
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 220px;
    
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 60px;
    
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4);
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.header-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header-button-text {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    
    
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем вам нужен именно `position:absolution`? Если его убрать и применить стиль `margin: 0 auto;` к элементу `.header-button`, то этот элемент будет центрироваться автоматически, независимо от изменения размеров родителя.
Если позволите, несколько советов:

1. Лучше избегать позиционирования в стиле `left: 10px, right -15px, bottom: 123.7px` (все вместе) и так далее. Эти решения не ситуативны, то есть при изменении макета все может "поехать". Сейчас очень много технологий, которые позволяют верстать блоками: flex (который вы используете), grid, где позиционирование указывается лаконичнее.
2. стили `margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;` для лучшей читаемости можно заменить на `margin: 8px;`
3. С точки зрения семантики будет правильней тег `<a>` поместить внутрь блочного тега `<div>`. Функционал не пострадает, зато подобные решения в будущем помогут избежать головной боли :)

```html
<a class="header-link" href="#">
   <div class="header-button">
      <div class="header-button-text">Go ahead
      </div>
   </div>
</a>

//почему не так?
<div class="header-button">
  <a class="header-link" href="#">Go ahead</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Я использовал абсолютное позиционирование по той причине, что блоку нужно наполовину вылазить из <header>, и думал, что margin просто потянет этот блок вниз и создаст ненужное пространство, поэтому и не стал его использовать. 
Что касательно тега <a>,то поместил его перед блочным элементом для того, чтобы ссылка распространялась на всю составляющую кнопки, то бишь не только текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-button{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
}
```

Comment: И вместо маргина можно `transform: translateX(-50%)` чтобы не зависело от размера кнопки

Comment: не совсем понимаю, а как высчитать нужный маргин ? почему именно 110 ? и почему именно маргин ?

Comment: ну он равен половине ширины блока. В данном случае маргин делает отступ "наоборот"
А так выше уже написали что вместо марджина лучше использовать transform: translateX(-50%)

Answer (score 0):

Помещать тег `a` внутрь `div` - невалидно, нельзя блочный элемент помещать в строчный, даже если это переопределено стилями.

Размещать кнопку по центру вероятно правильней через центрирование либо внутри flex-контейнера, либо как inline-block и центрирование текста.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 58px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  /* чтобы опустить кнопку относительно этого блока */
  /* height: 500px; - не стоит ограничивать высоту, на мобильных контент попадет за пределы блока, лучше добавить отступ снизу */
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.section2 {
  position: relative;
}

.header-intro {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  margin: 0 15px;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

.header-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: white;
}

.title-text {
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 0 35px 10px 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.subtitle-text {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.header-button {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* чтобы половина кнопки была ниже блока*/
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  /* фиксированная высота и ширина кнопке не нужна - ее размеры задаются динамичеки, шрифтом и отступами */
}

.header-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4);
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-button-text {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-intro">
      <div class="logo"> Logo
      </div>

      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">Start</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">About me</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">Work</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="section2">

      <div class="header-title">
        <div class="header-title-item">
          <h1 class="title-text">May I introduce myself?</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="header-subtitle-item">
          <h2 class="subtitle-text">Frontend Design | UI/UX Design
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="header-button">
      <a class="header-link" href="#">
        <div class="header-button-text">
          Go ahead
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблема заключается в том, что я ограничил высоту <header> лишь для того, чтобы фон занимал нужное пространство. Если говорить про элемент <a>, то я поместил его снаружи контейнера для того, чтобы ссылка работала для всех его элементов, то бишь, чтобы при наведении на любую часть блока она работала.

Comment: Если для тега A добавить свойство inline-block - то активной будет вся кнопка. Ограничение header приводит к проблемам на мобильных устройствах, как я писал. Если вы хотите задавать высоту блоку на определенных экранах - используйте медиа-запросы.